# Setting Order Status and adding custom carriers in Magento 1.5.1.0

Tags: magento

i am trying to create a order and assign a shipping no for that order when a order is placed. But i see that when i have an invoice created and a shipment added , magento sets the order status to 'complete' automatically. I tried to change the status manually but it wouldn work.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
            $order->save();
```

Could some one suggest me how to over come this? 
Also, how i add a custom carrier ? The default ones are DHL, FedEx , UPS.. I want to add one similar to them. This is how i am doing it:

```
$carrier = "dhl";
            $title = "DHL";
            $trackNumber = '538099';
            if (1) {
                $itemsQty = $order->getItemsCollection()->count();

    $shipment =Mage::getModel('sales/service_order',$order)->prepareShipment($itemsQty);
                $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
                $shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);


$shipment->addTrack($shipmentId,$carrier,$title,$trackNumber);
        }
```

For the carrier and title, if i give a custom name, i get a error invalid carrier in a report. How do i go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to make [a custom shipping module](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/)?

Comment: Currently i am not looking to have a custom shipping module. I am using table rates method as a shipping module. But i need to add a local carrier , so that i can add a tracking number for a shipment. The only options that are available for carriers are, DHL, FEDEX , UPS and USPS. Do i need to create a custom shipping module to add a custom carrier? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **addStatusToHistory** function. This is also used for adding comments.

```
$order->addStatusToHistory('processing', 'Order is being processed', false);
```

- param 1 (string): The new status
- param 2 (string): Your Comment
- param 3 (boolean): If you want to send the customer an email notification.